# Display timezone adjusted date and time from mongoDB in angular using moment or moment-timezone

Tags: angular, mongodb, momentjs, moment-timezone

I have a scheduled field in MongoDB that is date time, an example being:

```
"scheduled" : ISODate("2019-09-17T09:00:00Z")
```

I'm in the Eastern Time Zone, and so are all my clients.  What on earth do I need to do to get times to display and update using EST?

I try displaying the date by itself, without moment.js, and it displays as **9/17/19, 5:00 AM**, but the appointment time is actually at 9AM.

When I used moment-timezone, it still displayed as 5AM.

The only way I can get it to display correctly is doing this(which I do not understand, since I'd have thought -4 or something like that would work but it doesn't):

```
const scheduledtime = moment(scheduled)
              .utcOffset(0)
              .format('MM/DD/YY hh:mm a');
```

When I try to use `scheduledtime = moment(scheduled).tz('America/New_York').format('MM/DD/YY hh:mm a');` it shows as 5AM.  If I use `scheduledtime = moment(scheduled).tz('America/New_York').format('z');` I get a pipe error.

Can someone please help me understand what I need to do to make this work?  I just don't get what's happening, and how to either save the dates correctly so they display without adjustment OR how to display them appropriately.

Comment: Did I go wrong by putting a Z in there?  From what I've read, it looks like that makes it a 0 offset, but I just don't get this whole UTC/ISO date thing.

Comment: When you are doing moment(scheduled) , it is considering utc format. So when you are converting it to est format, it is subtracting 4 hours from it, i.e. why you are getting 5am instead of 9am.